# Merge rows with same in table postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

I have following table in postgresql:

```
id | grade | comment
--------------------
01 | A     | Good
01 | B     | OK
01 | C     | BAD
02 | A     | Good
02 | E     | Very BAD
02 | D     | BAD
```

I want to fetch records in following format

```
id | grade1 | grade2 | grade3 | comment1 | comment2 | comment3  
--------------------------------------------------------------
01 | A      | B      | C      | Good     | OK       | BAD
02 | A      | E      | D      | Good     | Very BAD | BAD
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    max(grade)   filter(where rn = 1) grade1,
    max(grade)   filter(where rn = 2) grade2,
    max(grade)   filter(where rn = 3) grade3,
    max(comment) filter(where rn = 1) comment1,
    max(comment) filter(where rn = 2) comment2,
    max(comment) filter(where rn = 3) comment3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by grade) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give this to me in fiddler?

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results seem to imply that the results are in some order.  No column contains that ordering.

One method is to just put the values in arrays:

```
select id, array_agg(grade order by <ordering col>) as grades,
       array_agg(comment order by ?) as comment
from t
group by id;
```

You can expand this to multiple columns:

```
select id,
       (array_agg(grade order by <ordering col>))[1] as grade_1,
       (array_agg(grade order by <ordering col>))[2] as grade_2,
       (array_agg(grade order by <ordering col>))[3] as grade_3
       (array_agg(comment order by <ordering col>)[1] as comment_1,
       (array_agg(comment order by <ordering col>)[2] as comment_2,
       (array_agg(comment order by <ordering col>)[3] as comment_3
from t
group by id;
```